# Map word ngrams to counts in scala

Tags: scala, nlp, n-gram

I'm trying to create a map which goes through all the ngrams in a document and counts how often they appear. Ngrams are sets of n consecutive words in a sentence (so in the last sentence, (Ngrams, are) is a 2-gram, (are, sets) is the next 2-gram, and so on). I already have code that creates a document from a file and parses it into sentences. I also have a function to count the ngrams in a sentence, ngramsInSentence, which returns Seq[Ngram].

I'm getting stuck syntactically on how to create my counts map. I am iterating through all the ngrams in the document in the for loop, but don't know how to map the ngrams to the count of how often they occur. I'm fairly new to Scala and the syntax is evading me, although I'm clear conceptually on what I need!

```
def getNGramCounts(document: Document, n: Int): Counts = {
    for (sentence <- document.sentences; ngram <- nGramsInSentence(sentence,n))
      //I need code here to map ngram -> count how many times ngram appears in document
}
```

The type Counts above, as well as Ngram, are defined as:

```
type Counts = Map[NGram, Double]
type NGram = Seq[String]
```

Does anyone know the syntax to map the ngrams from the for loop to a count of how often they occur? Please let me know if you'd like more details on the problem.

Comment: The below response looks like the way to go, but returns Map[Nothing,Int] instead of Map[NGram,Double], anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If I'm correctly interpreting your code, this is a fairly common task.

```
def getNGramCounts(document: Document, n: Int): Counts = {
  val allNGrams: Seq[NGram] = for {
    sentence <- document.sentences
    ngram <- nGramsInSentence(sentence, n)
  } yield ngram

  allNgrams.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size.toDouble)
}
```

The `allNGrams` variable collects a list of all the NGrams appearing in the document.
You should eventually turn to `Stream`s if the document is big and you can't hold the whole sequence in memory.

The following `groupBy`creates a `Map[NGram, List[NGram]]` which groups your values by its identity (the argument to the method defines the criteria for "aggregate identification") and groups the corresponding values in a list.

You then only need to map the values (the `List[NGram]`) to its `size` to get how many recurring values there were of each `NGram`.

---

I took for granted that:

1. `NGram` has the expected correct implementation of `equals` + `hashcode`
2. `document.sentences` returns a `Seq[...]`. If not you should expect `allNGrams` to be of the corresponding collection type.

---

**UPDATED** based on the comments

I wrongly assumed that the `groupBy(_)` would shortcut the input value. Use the `identity` function instead.

I converted the count to a `Double`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help. Unfortunately the above returns Map[Nothing, Int] rather than type Counts, implemented as Map[NGram, Double], with NGram implement as Seq[String]. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: You're right that sentences returns Seq[Sentence]. Sentence is implemented elsewhere.

Comment: A bare `_` doesn't work like you'd expect in this context. Try `.groupBy(x => x)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate the help - I have the correct code now using the suggestions above. The following returns the desired result:

```
def getNGramCounts(document: Document, n: Int): Counts = {
  val allNGrams: Seq[NGram] = (for(sentence <- document.sentences; 
                                   ngram <- ngramsInSentence(sentence,n)) 
                                yield ngram)
  allNGrams.groupBy(l => l).map(t => (t._1, t._2.length.toDouble))
}
```